# Strapi throw "Parse Error Request Aborted"

Tags: parsing, amazon-s3, strapi, formidable

[image]

[image]

Hello, once inn a while, i get the Error on the picture below.

People uploading image and sometimes this trow this error

Im using Strapi and AWS S3, i check my request, send the correct type of data, send pictures 3 by 3 to reduce the size of the PUT and POST request

I increase the server timeout, the MaxFileSize and the Formdata limit in strapi

I someone have an idea of what is going on and how to fix it

thanks in advance